# Replacing a div tag using replaceWith

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to replace this div or remove the data-overlay parameter (either will suit my purposes) and I have no control over the html.

```
<div class="page-header-overlay-color" data-overlay-opacity="default"</div>
```

I've been trying to use replaceWith, but however I write the code I end up with some version of `$ is not a function`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.page-header-overlay-color').replaceWith('<div class="page-header-overlay-color">');
});
```

This should work, jsfiddle doesn't generate any errors, but bewilderingly it does not work on live. Any tips on what I'm missing appreciated.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? replaceWith was added in jQuery 1.2

Comment: Also what is the exact error message? **$ is not a function** usually happens when you haven't included jquery in your code or have added multiple versions which conflict with each other

Comment: "$ is not a function"  it means jquery is not imported to you're document ( in case if  you are using wordpress replace  $ with  "JQuery"

Comment: Does it work with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...` ? Wordpress for example uses `jQuery.noConflict()` to prevent other libraries colliding with `$`

Comment: @CyC0der post that as an answer, I am using wordpress and you hit the nail on the head!